# поворот объекта округляется до 90 или -90 вокруг оси Y после движения

Tags: unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AgentPlayer : Agent
{
//"Horizontal"
    [SerializeField]
    string _movementX;
//"Vertical"
    [SerializeField]
    string _movementZ;

    [SerializeField]
    float _speed;

    float _moveX;
    float _moveZ;

    public override void Update()
    {
        _moveX = Input.GetAxis(_movementX);
        _moveZ = Input.GetAxis(_movementZ);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
//rb - rigidbody
        if (rb != null)
        {
            Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(_moveX, 0, _moveZ) * _speed;
            rb.AddForce(moveVector, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            transform.LookAt(transform.position + rb.velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

внезапно обнаруженная проблема в transform.LookAt. пожалуй LookAt - вообще плохой подход...

Answer (score 0):

У тебя когда rb.velocity становится близким или равным 0, то обьект пытается смотреть на свое положение, а изза погрешностей получает то в одну сторону, то в другую. Проверяй velocity на длину, чтобы была не меньше 1e-05f.